# If a matrix is invertible, how do we prove that its principal submatrices are invertible?

Tags: matrices

Is there a way to prove that if a square matrix A is invertible, that its principal submatrices are also invertible? I can imagine how you might prove this by thinking about the problem in terms of a Gauss-Jordan elimination, but is there a more elegant way to prove this?

Answer (score 6):

The claim you are looking to prove is false, at least by the definition of principal submatrix I am familiar with. Consider as a counterexample:

$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}1&1&1\\1&1&0\\1&0&0\end{matrix}\right]$$

Now $A$ is clearly invertable, but has as a principal submatrix the non-invertable $B$:

$$B=\left[\begin{matrix}1&1\\1&1\end{matrix}\right]$$